# How to get the caller's info When a app using URL Scheme to open my App in iOS

Tags: ios, url

In my situation, a third-party app will using URL Scheme to open my App in iOS, but my App must get some information about the caller, like caller's app name, caller's app icon.

How to do this ? or Is there another way to solve the situation?

Answer (score 1):

If you implement `openURL` in your `AppDelegate`, you can get some of those value, app icon is not possible though, you have to prepare it yourself or the scheme must somehow have it as url/data:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        print("source \(sourceApplication)")
        print("scheme \(url.scheme)")
        print("query \(url.query)")
        print("full \(url.absoluteString)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS can bind your app and a custom URL Scheme. With this URL Scheme you can
launch your app from browser or other app.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

You create the URL Scheme like snapshot:

```
URL Scheme: myapp
URL identifier: com.ypd.myapp
```

Then you can send URL like this below:

```
myapp://
myapp://example/path/here
myapp://?param1=1&param2=2
myapp://some/path/here?param1=1&param2=2
```

From the delegate method, you can get the deliver data:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url   
{  
    // Do something with the url here  
}
```

Comment: What your said does not solve my situation. My app want to identify which app send the URL.